# Not Returning Text Within Span Tag bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, findall

Im trying to scrape baseball odds for a range of dates from https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/totals/?date=20210615

I'm having a bit of trouble extracting text within span tags. For instance, say I just want all the opening odds from the table (from the third column) on June 15th, 2021.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# So we aren't identified as a bot
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',})

# get soup
page = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/totals/?date=20210615', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Get table rows (ie; one for each game)
table = soup.find('div', {'class':'eventsByLeague-2wGLV'})
table_rows = table.find_all('div', {'class':'eventMarketGridContainer-3QipG'})

# Iterate through table rows, extracting opening odds

for row in table_rows:
    
    # Get odds (Defined by class margin-2SxKQ)
    oddsrow = row.find_all('span', {'class':'margin-2SxKQ'})
    
    print(oddsrow)
    print('===================================')
```

The text I want (ie; 8, -120) is completely left out of odds row. In fact, the entire span tag containing total runs over/under (8) doesn't even show up. The span tag containing odds (-120) leaves out the number and just returns "-". Screenshot of inspected source attached.

[image: source code]

Comment: The table data is generated dynamically by javascript, so it isn't visible for `requests`. You can try `Selenium` or `pyppeteer` instead.

Comment: Right. It's strange because I don't have a problem extracting anything else in the table. Is your suspicion about the table being dynamically updated just an artifact of my above code not working, or is there something in the source that indicates this is the case?

Comment: You can check it fairly easily as follows: Deactivate Javascript in your browser and reload the page. If the desired data is missing (like in your case), it is dynamically loaded by javascript.